# Перемещение файла в корзину

Tags: c#

Имеется заданный путь к файлу, подскажите, как переместить его в корзину?

Comment: А за что минус? Валидный вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по всему, встроенного метода в C# и BCL нет. Но можно подключить метод из Visual Basic'а. Для этого добавьте ссылку на `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` и напишите в коде

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
```

```
FileSystem.DeleteFile(path, UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
```

Документация: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127976(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Любопытно, но действительно нет. По крайней мере об этом пишут во всех вопросах на en-so. Один из последних найденных примеров [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3282418/5752652).

Comment: @AK: Ага. Судя по всему, это _слишком уж_ некроссплатформенно. Но я ожидал бы от Microsoft отдельную библиотеку поддержки Shell.

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, тебе подойдет [`SHFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx) из [`shell32.dll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776426(v=vs.85).aspx). Пример реализации можешь посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282481/7099288).